# How to change taxonomy term path for table and grid view

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, path-aliases

I am using taxonomy term module. I have categories vocabulary and in term so many categories and I have created the view using taxonomy term.

With two page first is in table format and another is grid format and in both view page header I place the two icon one is list icon and another is matrix icon.

My issue are that when I click on list icon the page redirect to table view and path are show `taxonomy/term/%` but I want show the path in this format `[vocabulary name]/[term name]/[tid]/list`

Comment: did you used alias module??

Comment: yes i used alias module and path auto module

Comment: Then you can add custom alias

Comment: @AnkitGupta did you try my answer?

Comment: @Sssweat I try your answer but my issue is in my view i have one link in header then i click on this link i show matrix format of related contents and in matrix view same as link but this is tabl format .

so my issuse regarding that path 

here i click on matrix view the url show taxonomy/term/% but i want 
[vocabulary name]/[term name]/[tid]/grid

and on click tabl format i want [vocabulary name]/[term name]/[tid]/list url

Answer (score 0):

In [Pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto), for taxonomy term paths, put

```
[term:vocabulary]/[term:name]/[term:tid]/list
```

Then click on the **Bulk Update** tab and check mark **Taxonomy term paths** and then click **Update**.
[image]